# Cypress test hangs with custom command but not if using function in PO file - what am I getting wrong?

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I'm still kinda new to Cypress, so please forgive any noob ignorance - but...

I'm using page objects, and trying to use a custom command that I've written as a kind of wrapper around assertions. This custom command will be used across a number of tests, and a number of page object files, so I don't want to replicate the code for it in each page object file. But! If I put the exact same code into the page object definition it works fine, if I use it as a custom command, the test hangs (elapsed time just goes up and up, but nothing happens)... A rough illustration of what I'm doing:

```
myPage.myFirstElement.click()
myPage.mySecondElement.type('something')
myPage.want(myPage.ThirdElement, 'to equal', 'Fred') // want is the name of my custom command / function in the PO file
```

The above works. However, if I move 'want' to a custom command:

```
myPage.myFirstElement.click()
myPage.mySecondElement.type('something')
cy.want(myPage.ThirdElement, 'to equal', 'Fred') // want is the name of my custom command / function in the PO file
```

This hangs, as described above. I've tried setting prevSubject in my custom command definition, to no avail. I've also tried using .then(...), also to no avail.

What am I failing to spot / understand correctly?

Thank you :)

//EDIT : Code for 'want' function as requested. This is as it is when in my po file. When a custom command, it is identical in content, except of course the declaration reads "Cypress.Commands.Add('want', (val1, op, val2) => { " and so on...

```
    want(val1, op, val2) {

        function getContent(obj, op) {
            if ((op.indexOf('exist') >= 0) || (op.indexOf('visible') >= 0) || (typeof obj != 'object')) {
                return obj
            }
            return obj === null ? obj : obj.attr('value') === undefined ? obj.text() : obj.attr('value');
        }

        function compare(first, second) {
            op = op.split(' ').join('.')
            var cmp1 = getContent(first, op);
            var cmp2 = getContent(second, op);
            var assertFn = (op.indexOf('exist') >= 0) || (op.indexOf('visible') >= 0) ? 'expect' : 'softExpect'
            if (cmp2 === undefined) {
                var chaiAssertion = new Function('a', 'return chai.' + assertFn + '(a).' + op)
                chaiAssertion(cmp1)
                //.then({timeout: Cypress.config('responseTimeout')}, () => { return originalFn(cmp1)})
            } else {
                var chaiAssertion = new Function('a, b', 'return chai.' + assertFn + '(a).' + op + '(b)')
                chaiAssertion(cmp1, cmp2)
            }
        }

        if (typeof (val1) === 'object' && val1 != null) {
            val1.should(($v1) => {
                if (typeof (val2) === 'object' && val2 != null) {
                    val2.should(($v2) => {
                        compare($v1, $v2)
                    })
                }
                else {
                    compare($v1, val2)
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            if (typeof (val2) === 'object' && val2 != null) {
                val2.should(($v2) => {
                    compare(val1, $v2)
                })
            }
            else {
                compare(val1, val2)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you created custom command, this means you have to use like any other command in cypress:
cy.[command]

so it should work with :

```
cy.want(myPage.ThirdElement, 'to equal', 'Fred') // want is the name of my custom command / function in the PO file
```

Comment: But that's what I was saying - I would expect that to work, but it doesn't. With 'want' as a custom command, the test sits there, with the execution time continuing to go up, but nothing happens.... With 'want' as a function within the myPage class, it's fine

Comment: @user13123513 please share the want method on both places, so I can check.

Comment: Done as requested :)

Comment: were you able to look at this? Thanks!

Comment: @user13123513 it looks ok to me, it should work no matter where you add it.